# Parse asynchronous data loader (findInBackGround) does not reconnect to activity

Tags: android

On my android app, I use the Parse.com online database to store my data. In the `onCreate()` method of my activity, I use the method `findInBackground()` to asynchronously load data.

The `findInBackground()` method does not initially reconnect to the activity and continue to run forever. However, if I click on the home button of my phone and then re-load the app, the `findInBackGround()` method finally reconnects and load the data.

I would like to:

1. make the `findInBackground()` method reconnect with the activity without needing to reload the app
2. show a loading image (animated gif ?) while data is loading.

Would you guys have any advice on my problem ?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Alex

PS: I already tried the find() method of parse. Even if it reconnects automatically with the app, I don't think it's the right way to proceed since it blocks the UI of the caller activity until data is loaded.

**==================================================================================
I finally found the answers to my questions:**

1. I put the code to populate the listView INSIDE a method of the findCallBack class. Thus, I make sure I will use the result of the findInBackground() method only AFTER it has finished run. Previously, I had put the code to populate the listView OUTSIDE of the findCallBack class, so even if it came after in my code, it was actually executed before the end of findInBackground(), so didn't work.
2. For the loading image, I used an answer found on this site, which consists in activitating and stopping a ProgressDialog at the appropriate time (before and after findInBackground()).

   ```
                       startLoading(); //Show the loading image
                       query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
                           public void done(List<ParseObject> allQuestionsVal, ParseException e) {
                               if (e == null) {                           
                                   for(int i = 0; i<=allQuestionsVal.size()-1;i++){

                                       ParseObject questionVal = allQuestionsVal.get(i);   
                                       Question question = new Question(questionVal.getObjectId(), 
                                               questionVal.getString("FIELD1"), 
                                               questionVal.getString("FIELD2"),

                                       allQuestions.add(question);
                                   }                       
                                   stopLoading(); //Remove the loading image

                                   //Use the result of the Query (allQuestions) to populate listVIew
                                   ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.all_questions);        
                                   AllQuestionsAdapter adapter=new AllQuestionsAdapter(AllQuestions.this, allQuestions);
                                   list.setAdapter(adapter);               

                               } 
                               else {      
                                       stopLoading(); //Remove the loading image
                                   }
                               }
                           });
   ```

   protected ProgressDialog proDialog;

   ```
   protected void startLoading() {
       proDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
       proDialog.setMessage("loading...");
       proDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
       proDialog.setCancelable(false);
       proDialog.show();
   }

   protected void stopLoading() {
       proDialog.dismiss();
       proDialog = null;
   }
   ```

PS: any comments are welcomed :)

Comment: You can post your own answer as an answer (rather than as an edit to your question) and award yourself the reputation points. Your question will then show up in search results as answered, which is useful.

Comment: Thx for the tip, but the website told me I still cannot answer my own questions as I don't have enough reputation points..